# Sharing a base class between two derived classes in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, derived

In this situation class A is a parent of classes B and C. The goal is to share state between the instances b and c. It's not about adding or overriding functions, but about the state value `a`.

```
 class A():
     def __init__(self):
         self.a ='a'
         print('@a')
 class B(A):
     def __init__(self):
         A.__init__(self)
         self.x = 'b'
 class C(A):
     def __init__(self):
         A.__init__(self)
         self.x = 'c'

 b = B()
 c = C()
 print(b.a, b.x)
 print(c.a, c.x)
```

The output is

```
 @a
 @a
 a b
 a c
```

I understand why this is happening; `__init__()` in A is being called twice. I could put a test in so it only sets the initial value once, but that does not seem to be a very elegant solution. Additionally it only allows one instance of A to be shared. If I want another instance of A to be shared between two other instance of B and C it can't be done. The same goes for making `a` global inside the module and getting rid of class A entirely. Is there a good Pythonic way to solve this provlem?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question, could you clarify?

Comment: I think you may be confusing classes with instances of those classes. Your `b` and `c` are both `A` instances as well as `B` or `C` instances, but they're not the _same_ `A` instance, any more than `a1 = A()` and `a2 = A()` would be. So they don't have the same `a` member. So your question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors, please clean it up.

Comment: Exactly @abarnert, I was confused and you clarified what I did not understand. There are two instances of the `A` class created. Is there any way to create a single class instance that can be the parent to more then one class. In my example this would mean that there is only one `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with abarnert: this doesn't make any sense. This isn't what inheritance means.

Inheritance means that every B instance *is* an A instance, and every C instance *is* an A instance. A B instance doesn't have a separate A instance, and it certainly can't share with a C instance.

If you want B and C objects to *have* an A instance, and to have the *same* A instance, then you need composition:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = whatever()
        self.other_state = more_stuff()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A()
b = B(a)
c = C(a)
```

Now `b` and `c` are both sharing a single instance of `A`, and changes to that shared instance will be visible through both objects.